Why is the path not resolving to an absolute path for the data_dir that is passed as method parameter?
I have the following project structure in a Python project:
> nn-project  
   -.env
   - data
     - raw
       - boston_housing_price
>  - src
>    - models
>      - bird-model
>        - env.py
>        - train_model.py

I have in my .env file, the following:
PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER = ../

In my env.py, I do the following:
project_root = os.environ.get('PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER')
if not project_root:
    raise ValueError("PROJECT_ROOT environment variable is not set.")
absolute_path = os.path.abspath(project_root)
data_dir = Path(os.path.join(absolute_path, 'data/raw/boston_housing_price/'))
models_dir = Path(os.path.join(absolute_path, 'models/boston_housing_price/'))
print('***************** LOAD ENVIRONMENT ********************+')
print("Project Root DIR", project_root)
print("Project Root DIR abs", absolute_path)
print("Project Data DIR", data_dir)
print("Models Dump DIR", models_dir)
print('***************** LOAD ENVIRONMENT ********************+')

I get to see the following printed:
***************** LOAD ENVIRONMENT ********************+
Project Root DIR ../nn-project/
Project Root DIR abs /home/user/Projects/Private/ml-projects/nn-project
Project Data DIR /home/user/Projects/Private/ml-projects/nn-project/data/raw/boston_housing_price
Models Dump DIR /home/user/Projects/Private/ml-projects/nn-project/models/boston_housing_price
***************** LOAD ENVIRONMENT ********************+

I then have the following method in train_model.py that is supposed to load the dataset:
def load_data(data_dir):
    print(data_dir)
    # Check if the dataset file exists in the data directory
    dataset_file = Path(os.path.join(data_dir, env.boston_dataset))
    print(dataset_file)
    if os.path.exists(dataset_file):
        # If the dataset file exists, load it directly
        raw_df = pd.read_csv(dataset_file, sep="\s+", skiprows=22, header=None)
    else:
        # If the dataset file doesn't exist, fetch it from the URL
        response = requests.get(env.boston_dataset_url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the CSV data from the response content
            csv_data = response.text
            raw_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), sep="\s+", skiprows=22, header=None)
            # Save the dataset to the data directory for future use
            raw_df.to_csv(dataset_file, index=False)
        else:
            print("Failed to fetch data from URL:", env.boston_dataset_url)
            return None
    return raw_df

I call it like this:
boston = train_model.load_data(data_dir=env.data_dir)

But it fails when I run it with the message:
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '../nn-project/data/raw/boston_housing_price'

Question is, why is it not respecting the full path of the data_dir that I pass in as parameter to the method?

How about if not os.path.exists(YOUR_DIR):     os.mkdir(YOUR_DIR)?

The specified path exists as it can be seen from my folder_strucrure!

When the computer tells you a file doesn’t exist, it’s nearly always right. Can you add more debugging details to reveal the current working directory and what files exactly exist when the code runs?

The question is why the path is not resolving to an absolute path for the data_dir that I pass in as method parameter!

I had to resolve the env file again like this: # Reload the env module to ensure changes are reflected
importlib.reload(env)

I'm running that from a Python notebook and I had to relaod(env) on the cell and it now works!

@joesan if that is the question why you title it with some random python and csv first?
